# galois group of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

let E be the field of order $p^{75}$. Compute the Galois group of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{F}_p)$

Any clues? I cant see how to compute the degree of extension directly. I thought of using “The order of a finite field is $p^n$ if and only if it is the splitting field of $X^{p^{n}}- X$” but that doesn’t help much.

Comment: It seems strange that you have been given this exercise without any hint. Anyway, the hint would be in two parts. What do you know about the order of the group,? And then, consider the *Frobenius automorphism*.

Comment: You can use the duplicate with $[E:\Bbb F_p]=75$. See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582076/compute-galois-group-of-mathbb-f-q-mathbb-f-p).